# Inherited Resources Deperecated on Rails 3...Responders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just started using InheritedResources for an application I'm building and when I looked at its Github page, it says it's deprecated, and that I should instead use Responders.

I am new to InheritedResources and Responders so I am confused, how can I get from Responders what I get in InheritedResources (complete REST actions base "template" code) when all I see from the documentation are FlashResponders and HTTPCacheResponders?

I have also taken a look at this one:

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/tag/inherited_resources/

so does that mean that no more "REST template code" for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The combination of `respond_with` (which is built in to Rails) in conjunction with the `responders` gem makes InheritedResources deprecated.

Please have a look at [this blog post](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering) for an excellent explanation and demonstration of how to create a RESTful controller using `respond_with`. Most of the controller actions are reduced to single lines of code; with InheritedResources it was possible to have a controller with no code (because it was hidden away in the gem), but Jose Valim (creator of InheritedResources) thought this was too obfuscated as per his quote:

> "I have found that the responders abstraction and custom Rails generators offer the perfect balance between hiding and showing too much logic."

The `responders` come into play if you want to automate any other parts of the controller action, for example, setting the flash messages.

---

UPDATE: For the commenter below who asked about the `destroy` action

```
def destroy
  record = Record.find(params[:id])
  flash[:notice] = "The record has been destroyed successfully" if record.destroy
  respond_with record
end
```

Comment: The responders gem provides FlashResponder which will set the appropriate flash messages for create, update, and destroy. @fringd